# iOS 7 Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

Trying to use a background image that is bigger that than the regular size with some details that hang off the bottom.

So I'm doing this to set the image:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_home.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setClipsToBounds:NO];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

And It's still getting clipped.

Some other things I've tried:

Splitting the image up in Photoshop and setting the top 44points (the size that logs out when I log out the `navigationBar`'s frame) to the `backgroundImage` and the rest to the `shadowImage`.

From memory this worked fine in iOS 5, 6.

Is there a nice way to do this now? Thanks :)

Comment: can you put image pic in your question for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that I remember from one of the WWDC 2013 videos that what you were doing in iOS 5 and 6 (nav bar background view larger than the nav bar "with some details hanging off it") was considered wrong and they are no longer allowing it.

However, if you are supplying your own background image you can add a custom shadow image.